# Is the "First Posts" review queue partially broken?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review-page

Since March 19th, the number of reviewable "First Posts" has declined considerably. At first I suspected a yet-to-be-announced feature change in the review system, e.g. "First Posts" that receive votes or comments after a few minutes won't show up in the review queue anymore (i.e., are considered "reviewed" implicitly). However, the question [Asana Math + XeLaTeX: missing math upon resaving or editing in Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103584/asana-math-xelatex-missing-math-upon-resaving-or-editing-in-adobe-acrobat-pro) didn't show up for review for 20 minutes (after which it received a comment), and doesn't show up right now. Taking a second look at the [Review history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history), every "First Post" reviewed after March 19th, 18:00 GMT (20 so far) has been an *answer* -- it seems "First" *questions* simply don't show up in the review queue at all.

So: Is the "First Posts" review queue partially broken?

Comment: I have reviewed "First Posts" recently from New users and left welcome comments and duplicates, is it related to this ?

Comment: @texenthusiast It is -- the issue is that first *questions* used to show up in that queue, but are missing now.

Comment: May be TeX.SX passes to online people available for review due to work load distribution. I have no idea :).

Comment: This happened a couple of minutes ago: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z7zrc.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the "First Posts" review queue is working properly again. Congratulations to everyone who was part of the "150 reviewable First Posts" party in the late evening of March 27th. ;-)

Comment: And congratulations to you for the [Steward](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/212/steward) badge for first posts. `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks. It seems you'll also get this badge in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: I missed it.  Right on my birthday, too.  Sounds like it was amazing.  :'(